# light box modal for images in a web page

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, lightbox

The following code is to retrieve 3 images and display in a table! i have imported the necessary jquery library and css script to implement the light box modal!

```
            <?php
                require("includes/db.php");

                $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
                $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    echo"<head>";
    echo"<link rel='stylesheet' href='lightbox.css'>";
    echo"<script type='text/javascript' src='lightbox.min.js'>";
    echo"</script>";
    echo"</head>";

    echo "<body bgcolor=#E6E6FA>";
    echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 > " ;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).'  data-lightbox="gallery"  >';
   echo "<img src='" .$row['Image1']. "' height='200' width='200'/>";
    echo "</a>";


    echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center >";


    if($row['Image2']=="No copy"){
        echo "No copy";
    }
    else{
     echo '<a href='.( $row['Image2'] ).' data-lightbox="gallery" >';
   echo "<img src='" . $row['Image2'] . "' height='200' width='200'/>";
    }
    echo "</a>";


    echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
      echo"<td align=center >";

  if($row['Image3']=="No copy"){
        echo "No copy";
    }
    else{
     echo '<a href='.( $row['Image3'] ).'  data-lightbox="gallery"  >';
   echo "<img src='" . $row['Image3'] . "' height='200' width='200'/>";
    }
   echo "</a>";


    echo "<br>";


     echo"</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

   ?>
```

The above code does not work please help me! how do i need to corrrect the code?     I get the following errors in the developer tools!

```
lightbox.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
http://localhost/project1/test/images/close.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/project1/test/images/prev.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/project1/test/images/next.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/project1/test/images/loading.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: use lightbox.js so that it will give full details about error, minified file doesn't give full error message.

Comment: corrected the error but light box model method is not implemented

Comment: can you create a js fiddle and then i will correct it, or can you give some error information from console?

Comment: now no errors but when i click on an image it just enlarges into another page as if the lightbox.js features has not been imported!  i think some problem in implementing the imported file

Comment: <a href='.( $row['Image1'] ).' this part i think prevents the implementation of library functions! i think it must be correted but i dont know how to because i am writing html in  a php script! i referred this video https://youtu.be/IPVQeVlw2_E but its in full html

Comment: just use var_dump($row['image1']); to check what is the value inside image1 key of your array, or check generated html what is substituted at that place using view source in browser.

Comment: Which lightbox plugin do you use?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `lightbox.min.js` file on line 12 not in this PHP code.

Comment: so i directly got it from the internet so it can;t have any issues right?